# Make button background transparent using selector

Tags: android, android-layout, nine-patch, android-selector

Here we go. I have a button that has a non-pressed state background as transparent. As soon as the button is pressed, the background is no longer transparent (see the pics). I use nine patch for all my images.

This is my selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/starfighterstartbtndown" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/starfighterstartbtn"/>
</selector>
```

And here is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/mainMenuImage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/starfighter" >

</ImageView>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttons"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnStart"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"
        android:src="@drawable/startselector" >

    </ImageButton>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnExit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/exitselector"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true" >
    </ImageButton>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Not Clicked:

[image: Not Clicked]

Clicked:

[image: Clicked]

I have also tried the following methods with no luck

```
button.getBackground().setAlpha(0);
button.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Also tried the following inside the onClickListener()

```
view.getBackground().setAlpha(0);
view.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
button.getBackground().setAlpha(0);
button.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Still no luck. Good luck :)

Comment: Is it possible that the second image resource file for the button is not transparent while the first one is?

Comment: Well that is embarrassing. Yes the "button down" .png didn't have a transparent background. If only programmers like me could think....

Answer (score 8):

to make your button's background transparent in *non pressed* state , your selector should be like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/starfighterstartbtndown" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>
</selector>
```

And in your imageButton's declaration in xml should use the selector as a background  and dont make anything as a source of your imageButton:

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnStart"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src="@drawable/startselector"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true" />
```

Comment: I'm using the selector to draw both the button at rest and the button down, so this wouldn't work

Comment: I take that back... with a condition. I understand using it as the background of the button, but you don't need the transparent statement for the selector as long as the patch 9 images for the button at rest/pressed have a transparent background

Comment: Sorry , you should make a selector to your src attribute with two images ( Start in both colors with transparent color in the background in both states ) , and add it as a src drawable for your ImageButton

Comment: An odd thing. Using color/transparent worked, but only after I did a Build->Clean. I am using the ADK. Annoying, but it did end up working.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Color.argb(). It takes four int parameters, each ranging from 0 to 255.

Let's say you want a blue button with 50% alpha:

```
button.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(125, 0, 0, 255));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also try this

```
<ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"/>
```