# How do I set a "pressed" imagebutton in Android Studio?

Tags: android, sdk

I have an ImageButton:

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:id="@+id/btn_70s"
    android:src="@drawable/btn_70s"
    android:background="@null" /* Sets transparent BG for button image(PNG) */
 />
```

The image is "btn_70s", how do I set a "pressed" version of the image for when the ImageButton is tapped?

The documentation states to create an XML file and place it in the drawable directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:state_pressed="true"
       android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" /> <!-- pressed -->
 <item android:state_focused="true"
       android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused" /> <!-- focused -->
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

This to me says it would affect all the ImageButtons rather than an individual one. Would I save it as an individual XML for each button for example (btn_70s_custom.xml), and then use it like:

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:id="@+id/btn_70s"
    android:src="@drawable/btn_70s"
    android:android:background="@drawable/btn_70s_custom"
 />
```

Only issue with this, I can't use @null to allow transparency. Any assistance is appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look over there for a (possible) solution to your problem : [Make button background transparent using selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17645521/make-button-background-transparent-using-selector)

And for the record,

> This to me says it would affect all the ImageButtons rather than an individual one. Would I save it as an individual XML for each button for example (btn_70s_custom.xml), and then use it like:

No, it won't set this theme for all the buttons, but only for the ones where you specify to use this selector.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can try selectableItemBackground

```
<ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"/>
```